# Error: Invalid login: Authentication unsuccessful

Tags: authentication, nodemailer

I have a problem when using the nodemailer package where it says Authentication unsuccessful , how to solve it

Error: Invalid login: 535 5.7.3 Authentication unsuccessful [SI2PR02CA0043.apcprd02.prod.outlook.com 2023-08-01T10:19:11.903Z 08DB9143449C8451]
at SMTPConnection._formatError (C:\Users\USER\Documents\mern-stack\inventory management app\backend\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp-connection\index.js:790:19)
at SMTPConnection._actionAUTHComplete (C:\Users\USER\Documents\mern-stack\inventory management app\backend\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp-connection\index.js:1564:34)
at SMTPConnection. (C:\Users\USER\Documents\mern-stack\inventory management app\backend\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp-connection\index.js:1518:18)
at SMTPConnection._processResponse (C:\Users\USER\Documents\mern-stack\inventory management app\backend\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp-connection\index.js:969:20)
at SMTPConnection._onData (C:\Users\USER\Documents\mern-stack\inventory management app\backend\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp-connection\index.js:755:14)
at TLSSocket.SMTPConnection._onSocketData (C:\Users\USER\Documents\mern-stack\inventory management app\backend\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp-connection\index.js:193:44)
at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:376:20)
at addChunk (internal/streams/readable.js:309:12)
at readableAddChunk (internal/streams/readable.js:284:9)
at TLSSocket.Readable.push (internal/streams/readable.js:223:10) {
code: 'EAUTH',
response: '535 5.7.3 Authentication unsuccessful [SI2PR02CA0043.apcprd02.prod.outlook.com 2023-08-01T10:19:11.903Z 08DB9143449C8451]',
responseCode: 535,
command: 'AUTH LOGIN'
}
undefined

sendEmail.js
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gDkLX.png)

.env
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PuJZz.png)